# Setting array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Noob question. Setting array elements throws an error.

I get this error when I run the script: array1[user_id] is undefined.

```
array1 = new Array();

// the data variable I got from a JSON source
// using jQuery
$.each(data, function(i, item) {

    // Set variables
    user_id = item.post.user_id;
    user = item.post.user;
    price = item.post.price;

    if (array1[user_id]['user'] != user) {
        array1[user_id]['price'] = price;
        array1[user_id]['user'] = user;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well.. I am trying to make more sense of it now...

Comment: It's not that bad, Cudos is clearly trying to define nested objects and doesn't realize each sub-object needs to be initialized independently.

Comment: @pst I am trying my best. I don't know about you but English is not my first language and javascript is pretty new to me. No reason to be rude.

Comment: @pst: did the OP not explain that the problem was that `array1[user_id] is undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not use an array, if you need a hash map, use objects. In some languages, it's one thing, but in JS they're not.

When defining a nested object you have to define each level as an object.

```
var hash = {};

// the data variable I got from a JSON source
$.each(data, function(i, item) {

    // Set variables
    user_id = item.post.user_id;
    user = item.post.user;
    price = item.post.price;
    // Have to define the nested object
    if ( !hash[user_id] ) {
        hash[user_id] = {};
    }
    if (hash[user_id]['user'] != user) {
        hash[user_id]['price'] = price;
        hash[user_id]['user'] = user;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: @Ivan - Nobody, but it often times makes life eas(ier).

Comment: @Ivan: the poster did, I just modified his original posting so it would work, I didn't add any jQuery. Read before you post and downvote!

Comment: Ah, you're right.  The poster should have mentioned it somewhere since I was thinking of a non-jquery solution.

Comment: @Ivan: What was the poster supposed to mention? I also can't stand people that use jQuery for every answer, but the question is clearly not about jQuery, it just uses jQuery as part of the example.

Comment: @Ivan: Why did you add the jQuery tag? Question is not about jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you have to initialize the first dimension of array1 first, like so:

```
array1[user_id] = {};
```

then you can do this:

```
array1[user_id]['user'] = 'whatever';
```

That is of course assuming your user_id is not undefined.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what the "user_id" variable is before I loop through the "data" variable.

Comment: Then I would use an object and `try` `catch`.